# Passing 2 variables with URL mod rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^shopName/([^/]+)/(.*)?$ contactus.php?shopName=$1&shopId=$2 [L,QSA]
```

My results URL is:

```
http://noblenetwork.net/shopName/Eyepax/5
```

I need to customize this URL as:

```
http://noblenetwork.net/Eyepax
```

I do not want to show the id in the URL. Please help me.

Comment: If `shopId` is required this is not possible

Comment: realy? it's ok. If I dont need the shopId, what will be the rewrite rule?

Comment: if you dont need it, better dont send it...change your url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.htaccess` code to

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ contactus.php?shopName=$1&shopId=$2 [L,QSA]
```

If shop id isn't passed `contactus.php` would receive it as `&shopId=` blank or null. So, you can use both

```
http://noblenetwork.net/Eyepax
http://noblenetwork.net/Eyepax/5
```

Comment: hi Ravi, this is working. but, it made my website very slow. do u have any idea about this issue?

Comment: @user2319101, can you test the website performance with rule disabled (just put a # in front of it)? This would help identify if the rule is really causing the problem. If you see marked improvements when the rule is off, please share the Tomcat rewrite logs when the rule is on and the website runs slow.